# Debug logs in abstract parent class not showing

Tags: apex, debugging, inheritance

I have some inheritance going in in classes and I need to know what is going on in the parent code.  For some reason, I can get debugs from the child class but not the parent.

Child class:

```
public with sharing class DetailSyncController extends BaseSyncController
{
  public DetailSyncController(String idVal)
  {
    super(idVal);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'made it here 3');
  }

  public DetailSyncController()
  {
    this(null);
  }
}
```

I can find the debug statement 'made it here 3' from the above.

Parent class:

```
public with sharing abstract class BaseSyncController
{
  public BaseSyncController(String idVal)
  {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'made it here 2');
  }
}
```

But the debug from the above ('made it here 2') does not display.  Why would this not show up in my debugs and how can I make it show up?

Answer (score 1):

I added exactly your two pieces of code to an org and executed:

```
new DetailSyncController();
```

in the Developer console and saw both messages in the expected 2 then 3 order in the log. So I don't know why you are not seeing the debug output.

Comment: Ya, this confuses me.  Everything I see tells me this should definitely be working.

Comment: @dphil The exact code you posted doesn't work for you?

Comment: The code there is a simplified version of the classes but I'll test it to see if there is anything different.  The flow should be exactly the same but I have some other things to finish up before i can test it some more.